# Install Shield error with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, installshield

My app is running right with the compiler, but when i create the installer with installshield throw me a error "No connection string named 'CardaniDBEntities' could"

This is what i actually added in the Appication Data

[Application Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWl53.png)

[Error Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcbRP.png)

I really dont know how to solve this, im using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to InstallShield

1)The app.config file is missing (YourAppName.config after the setup)
or
2)The file exists ,but the ConnectionStrings element is missing

Make sure that there is a file **Cardani Soft.config** next to your .exe file and that it contains the **ConnectionStrings** element